# Do you gather, collect, or receive points when taking an exam?

Tags: grammar, usage

Imagine I took an exam and got 50 points. Which of the following sound right to a native English speaker?

- I *gathered* 50 points.
- I *collected* 50 points.
- I *received* 50 points.
- Obtained/garnered/attained/... anything else?

I know that "get" is too informal.

Besides that, do you gather/collect/receive/... 50 points *from* the exam? *In* the exam? *At* the exam?

I am employed at a Slovenian university, and I am constantly struggling with expressions like these.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are the 50 points simply your mark from the exam or a form of credit for completing the exam?

Comment: _Collecting points_ sounds like a supermarket's reward scheme, and suggests you earned them a few at a time. If you consider _got_ too informal, you could say "I was awarded 50 marks".

Comment: It is a reasonable question but is best answered on English Language Learners Stack Exchange. As a native speaker I am happy with "got" and might also use "received". I would not use collect or gather, which both suggest the getting of the points was a matter of my selection and my grasping of them. It is not.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that "get" is too informal.

It's not too informal.

There are multiple ways to say this depending on the context. For example:

- *I got 50 points in the exam*
- *I scored 50 points in the exam*

You *take* or *sit* an exam and *get* or *score* points *in it*.

"*At the exam*" sounds like it refers to the actual event

- *I forgot everything I knew at the exam*

Comment: If the test was graded, in AE we'd say we got a 50 *on* the exam.